# Laravel 5.8: Insertion into database does not seem to be working

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, laravel-5.8

I am working on an Online Store and want to insert some payment details into `payments` table.

Everything works good except this insertion process that does insert data into table:

```
if (!empty($existPayment)) {
    $existPayment->delete();
    $payment = Payment::create([
        'pay_type_id' => '186',
        'pay_date' => jdate()->format('Y/m/d'),
        'pay_amount' => $order->ord_total * 10,
        'pay_ord_id' => $order->ord_id,
        'pay_status_id' => '182',
        'pay_creator_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
        'pay_confirm' => '1',
    ]);
}
```

So in order to know where the problem is coming from, I tried this:

```
if (!empty($existPayment)) {
    dd('Exists');
}
```

And I got the result `Exists`, then I tried:

```
if (!empty($existPayment)) {
        if($existPayment->delete()){
            dd('Deleted');
        }
    }
```

And again I got the correct result which is `Deleted`, after that I tried:

```
if (!empty($existPayment)) {
        $existPayment->delete();
        $payment = Payment::create([
            'pay_type_id' => '186',
            'pay_date' => jdate()->format('Y/m/d'),
            'pay_amount' => $order->ord_total * 10,
            'pay_ord_id' => $order->ord_id,
            'pay_status_id' => '182',
            'pay_creator_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
            'pay_confirm' => '1',
        ]);

        dd($payment);
    }
```

And I got this as result:

```
"pay_type_id" => "186"
"pay_date" => "1400/05/05"
"pay_amount" => 750000.0
"pay_ord_id" => 9222
"pay_status_id" => "182"
"pay_creator_id" => 2
"pay_confirm" => "1"
"updated_at" => "2021-07-27 12:12:06"
"created_at" => "2021-07-27 12:12:06"
"pay_id" => 8929
```

But when I check the DB, the data is not inserted somehow and I don't know why!

I also put this code in `try..catch` but didn't show any kinds of error.

So if you know how to solve this issue or any idea on how to debug it, please let me know...

I would really appreciate that.

Thanks in advance.

**MODEL:**

```
class Payment extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "payments";
    protected $primaryKey = "pay_id";
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $appends = [
        'status_label', 'type_label'
    ];
    protected $fillable = [
        'pay_type_id ','pay_date','pay_amount','pay_ord_id','pay_status_id','pay_creator_id','pay_confirm'   // all the columns you want
    ];
    ...
```

Comment: So Your data is not inserting Right?

Comment: @JEJ Yes it is not inserting !!

Comment: Does it Worked??

Comment: @JEJ Thanks for the anwer, I'm going to test it now

Comment: Okay Update me If Its not worked

Comment: @JEJ No it is not working, however I just added the `fillable`s at the Model. There's a problem somewhere

Comment: Check Your Model Imported

Comment: I just added Model info to the question

Comment: Can You specify what error it returns? in the laravel Log

Comment: Where is Laravel log ?

Comment: Try The first Method I mentioned and check . plz not that your Model should be in your Controller

Comment: Yes it is properly placed at the Controller and I just tested the first method as well.

Comment: You can find log by following `storage->logs->laravel.log'  remove all the codes in the log and save it and run again the code and check what error is returning in the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235329/discussion-between-jej-and-loctoj).

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 $payment = new Payment;
 $payment->pay_type_id = '186';
 $payment->pay_date = jdate()->format('Y/m/d');
 $payment->pay_amount = $order->ord_total * 10;
 $payment->pay_ord_id =  $order->ord_id;
 $payment->pay_status_id = '182';
 $payment->pay_creator_id = auth()->user()->usr_id;
 $payment->pay_confirm = '1';
 $payment->save();
```

You can Also Use an Easy Way By Using [Fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

For that In Your  Payment Model add

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'pay_type_id ','pay_amount '   // all the columns you want 
];
```

And use the Create method Mentioned In the Question

```
$payment = Payment::create([
        'pay_type_id' => '186',
        'pay_date' => jdate()->format('Y/m/d'),
        'pay_amount' => $order->ord_total * 10,
        'pay_ord_id' => $order->ord_id,
        'pay_status_id' => '182',
        'pay_creator_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
        'pay_confirm' => '1',
    ]);
```

**Note the Model Must be imported In Controller** `use App\Payment;`